# Mobile app recoring in jmeter getting error

Tags: android, jmeter

I am trying to record a mobile native app using jmeter. i have entered the proxy ip and the host and port of my jmeter machine to the wifi settings of my android device. Other natives app i am able to record in jmeter but with this specific app i am getting error as "you are not permitted to connect to this server" after invoking my app on my android device.

Please help.

Regards,
Kumar.